# How many nearest neighbors does the SSH model have?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I'm having some trouble understanding the SSH model. In the unit cell, it has 2 atoms, but the Hamiltonian for the nearest neighbor is written with only one term. (See below. The first two is on-site hopping and the 3rd and the 4th is nearest neighbor) Shouldn't it have 2, since an atom $a_i$ has nearest $b_{i+1}$ and $b_{i}$ next to it? For instance, in graphene we have the same thing, $a_i$ has 3 nearest neighbors $b$s. But for SSH we say it has 1 nearest neighbor. By the same logic, graphene should have 2. What am I missing?

$$H=\sum_i a_ib_i^{\dagger} + b_ia_i^{\dagger} + a_ib_{i+1}^{\dagger} + a_{i+1}b_i^{\dagger}$$

Comment: Can you write down the specific hamiltonian you're looking at?

Comment: Sure I added it.

Comment: A particle on an $A$ site can hop to its two neighboring $B$ sites. One of those sites is in the same unit cell (label $i$), the other is in an adjacent unit cell (label $i+i$). This is reflected in the hamiltonian. You say the hamiltonian only has one nearest-neighbor hopping term, but the $H$ you wrote down has two nearest-neighbor terms, so I am confused by what you are asking about.

Comment: I was confused by this source: https://phyx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/TI/Lecture%20notes/1.html 

In the nearest neighbor it doesn't have the i,i sites.